# how to set rgb color in android?

Tags: java, android, rgb, rgba

I am trying to set text background color using `text1.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(r,g,b));`

were red,green,blue values are coming from database based on value `i` set `r=128,g=255,b=128` programmatically it color was dull green but i run the program it will displayed red color

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = list.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable
           // String GRPCODE = c.getString(TAG_GRPCODE);
            String GRPNAME = c.getString(TAG_GRPNAME);
            String QTY = c.getString(TAG_QNT);
            String BUDGET = c.getString(TAG_BUDGET);
            String STOCK = c.getString(TAG_STOCK);
            String DIFF = c.getString(TAG_DIFF);
            String DIFF_P = c.getString(TAG_DIFF_P);

             COLOR = c.getString(TAG_COLOR);

            /*String[] ARGB = COLOR.split(" ");

             String V1=ARGB[0];
             String V2=ARGB[1];
             String V3=ARGB[2];
             String V4=ARGB[3];

             a=Integer.parseInt(V1);
             r=Integer.parseInt(V2);
             g=Integer.parseInt(V3);
             b=Integer.parseInt(V4);*/


            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
          //  map.put(TAG_GRPCODE, GRPCODE);
            map.put(TAG_GRPNAME, GRPNAME);

            map.put(TAG_QNT, QTY);
            map.put(TAG_BUDGET, BUDGET);
            map.put(TAG_STOCK, STOCK);
            map.put(TAG_DIFF, DIFF);
            map.put(TAG_DIFF_P, DIFF_P);

            map.put(TAG_COLOR,COLOR);
            //map.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            contactList.add(map);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    /**
     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
     * */
     ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, datatList,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] {  TAG_GRPNAME, TAG_QNT, TAG_BUDGET, TAG_STOCK, TAG_DIFF, TAG_DIFF_P, },
            new int[] {
                     R.id.l2, R.id.l3, R.id.l4, R.id.l5, R.id.l6, R.id.l7}){
         @Override
         public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
             View v = convertView;
             if (v == null) {
                 LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                 v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
             }
              text1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.l7);


             HashMap<String, String> map=dataList.get(position); 
             map.get(TAG_COLOR); 
             String[] ARGB = COLOR.split(" "); 
             String V1=ARGB[0]; 
             String V2=ARGB[1]; 
             String V3=ARGB[2]; 
             String V4=ARGB[3]; 
             a=Integer.parseInt(V1); 
             r=Integer.parseInt(V2); 
             g=Integer.parseInt(V3); 
             b=Integer.parseInt(V4); 

             text1.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(r,g,b));

             return super.getView(position, v, parent);
         }
     };
```

Comment: put a log statement before setbackgroundcolor, check if values are what you want

Comment: @OnurA. before set color i check it will correct

Comment: your views have all the same color? since in for loop everytime r,g,b values are changing your views using the last color value from the db

Comment: @OnurA. yup same color ..how to fix it plz temme

Comment: remove the color parsing code from the existing and then you should re-parse that color value again in getView()
`HashMap<String, String> map=contactList.get(position);
map.get(TAG_COLOR);
String[] ARGB = COLOR.split(" ");

             String V1=ARGB[0];
             String V2=ARGB[1];
             String V3=ARGB[2];
             String V4=ARGB[3];

             a=Integer.parseInt(V1);
             r=Integer.parseInt(V2);
             g=Integer.parseInt(V3);
             b=Integer.parseInt(V4);
text1.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(r,g,b));`

Comment: @OnurA. sorry it having the same prob

Comment: same prob? i didn't get that

Comment: @OnurA. i remove the color parsing and re-parse color value in getview (). it will get only last color in db.. anything i miss it

Comment: you are getting map from `dataList`, but in above code you put your map in `contactList`, so in your getview change it to this `contactList.get(position);`

Comment: @OnurA. i just changed obj name contactlist to datalist but i forget to change in stackoverflow its not a problem i still get last color of db..

Comment: hım do you check the db? are colors different?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> finally i got answer

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, dataList,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] {  TAG_GRPNAME, TAG_QNT, TAG_BUDGET, TAG_STOCK, TAG_DIFF, TAG_DIFF_P, },
            new int[] {
                     R.id.l2, R.id.l3, R.id.l4, R.id.l5, R.id.l6, R.id.l7}){
         @Override
         public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
             View v = convertView;
             if (v == null) {
                 LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                 v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
             }
              text1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.l7);

              String rgbColor=  dataList.get(position).get(TAG_COLOR);
              String[] ARGB = rgbColor.split(" ");     
              a=Integer.parseInt(ARGB[0]);
              r=Integer.parseInt(ARGB[1]);
              g=Integer.parseInt(ARGB[2]);
              b=Integer.parseInt(ARGB[3]);                        
              text1.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(r, g, b));
              return super.getView(position, v, parent);
          }

     };
```